# Is it possible to run PowerShell Core in a Linux dotnet container?

Tags: docker, .net-core, powershell-core

I can see there is no Powershell present in `microsoft/dotnet`:

```
C:\> docker run -it microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk bash
root@5397dac12c1e:/# pwsh
bash: pwsh: command not found
```

When I try to add it in the following way heavily inspired by [PowerShell dockerfiles](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/docker/release/ubuntu16.04/Dockerfile):

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk
RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends         apt-utils         ca-certificates         curl         apt-transport-https         locales    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add -
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/prod.list | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/microsoft.list
RUN apt-get update     && apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends     powershell
```

... step `RUN [...] apt-get install [...] powershell` fails with

```
Fetched 10.3 MB in 11s (914 kB/s)
Reading package lists...
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 powershell : Depends: libssl1.0.0 but it is not installable
              Depends: libicu55 but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I guess it was too bold to try to use Ubuntu approach inside of a Debian Stretch container. I wonder whether there is an easier way to get container that has both `dotnet-sdk` and `pwsh` present.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the simplest solution is just to wait for a new release of PowerShell Core [that's going to support Ubuntu 18.04](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/6942) -- and then match it with `dotnet:2.1-sdk-bionic`.